# Firebase Multilevel Child Query Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

How can i get All chats where Users contains a specific Uid

```
 Query sItemQuery = mDatabase.getReference().child("chats").limitToLast(200);

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<ChatMetaData> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<ChatMetaData>()
                        .setQuery(sItemQuery, ChatMetaData.class)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .build();
```

[image: This is my DB Structure]

Answer (score 2):

You can't query across multiple levels like that. See [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)

So while your current data structure makes it easy to find the current users in a chat, it doesn't make it easy to find the current chats for a user.

For that you'll need to add an additional data structure. Something like:

```
user_chats: {
  uid1: {
    chatid1: true,
    chatid2: true
  }
  uid2: {
    chatid2: true,
    chatid3: true
  }
}
```

With this additional structure, you can easily find the chats for the current user by reading `/user_chats/$uid`.

Also see:

- [Firebase query if child of child contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value)